# Is there any way to account for all delimiters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to create a word count for a book (.txt file) and I'm trying to split each line into its separate words using this:

```
temp = re.split('[; |, |\*|\n| |\|:|.|’|"|&|#|$|(|)|]|//|'']', line)
```

However, this isn't working because every time I run the program, I have to add another delimiter to the list. This time I have to add '-' and '%'. I remember doing something similar in Java where I could specify a 'range' of delimiters and when I tried the same thing here, it didn't seem to work.

Is there any better way to do this and make sure I just get the word and nothing else?

Comment: What is the rule that tells you whether something is a delimiter or not?

Comment: Parsing natural language is always going to be somewhat inexact. Getting mostly correct is usually good enough for statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `\W`, the set of all non-word characters, i.e. not a letter, digit, or underscore.

i.e.

```
temp = re.split('\W+', line)
```

---

By the way, characters inside a regex character set are mostly literal. Yours boils down to this:

```
[; |,*\n:.’"&#$()]/']
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will split words in the middle if they contain combining unicode characters.

Comment: @Pux Huh, I never thought about that. I think you could fix that by doing a Unicode normalization first. But IMO, based on OP's specification, this isn't meant to be precise. It'll also spilt words on hyphens and apostrophes like "co-ordinate" and "it's". If you want better splitting, you probably want a real NLP library.